# How to get Android MediaCodec return decoded frame immediately after feeding every frame

Tags: android, android-mediacodec

I am following the Google basic media decoder example to design the decoder. The decoder will not return decoded frame until few input buffers are filled. I guess this is fine for most applications. However, my application requires zero-latency, meaning each frame must be decoded before feeding next frame. Is there anyway to force decoder to decode a frame? I tried setting EOS on every frame but the following flush() will clear internal decoder state, leading to P frames undecodable.

Comment: Did you ever get to the bottom of this? I too have this problem.